# How to limit select count globally in spring data jpa?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Latest project I used Spring boot and Spring Data Jpa, and in some web interface user can dynamic search some records，e.g. search order by createdDate, search goods by name and so on. Because exist many search conditions, e.g name,brand,status and so on. So I used [Jpa Specification](https://github.com/springside/springside4/blob/4.0/modules/core/src/main/java/org/springside/modules/persistence/DynamicSpecifications.java) to implement dynamic search. So page could pass below query parameter to search records, e.g.

```
GET /goods?search_LIKE_name=foo #fuzzy search goods by name
GET /goods?search_LIKE_name=foo&search_EQ_status=1 #fuzzy search goods by name and status
```

and so on.

But if page pass nothing, then it will select all. I don't want this happen. And I know mysql command line have an option called [--select_limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_select_limit), So how could I configure it globally to limit select count? e.g. in application.properties

```
spring.sql_select_limit=1000
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a global configuration, but i have a relatively neat local solution. On controller method just use annotation `@PageableDefaults(pageNumber = 0, value = x)` before pageable.

*Controller method:*

```
public List<Item> fuzzySearch(Object filter, @PageableDefaults(pageNumber = 0, value = x) Pageable pageable) {}
```

If page parameters are missing default values specified in annotation will be used.

edit:

If you manage to rename paging parameters from request to *size* and *page* and use method signature with `Pageable` as parameter you can setup page default globally instead of putting `PageableDefaults` annotation where needed.
Just override method in the `@Configuration` class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    resolver.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, 1000));
    argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
    super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have no pageable parameter, I directly parse request parameter.   public List<Item> fuzzySearch(HttpServletRequest request) {}. If have no pageNumber in request, I'll explicitly assign a pageRequest parameter like this: findAll(spec,new PageRequest(0, 1000));

Comment: Ok, but if you have parameters named size and page in the request and you add Pageable as method parameter they will be automatically inferred as declared Pageable. So you could still use my answer.